# MQ Trigger to execute batch file

Tags: batch-file, triggers, websphere, message, broker

My scenario is the stop and start message flows using batch file, where I have mqsi commands. When I execute the batch file manually, I am able to stop and start the flow. When I try to execute the batch file using the trigger enabled on one particular queue, I get the following error,

---

C:\Program Files\IBM\MQSI\7.0\bin>mqsistopmsgflow DISSERTATION_MS -e WITH_WATCHDOG  -m WITH_WATCHDOG.MainFlow_Webservice_With_WatchDog Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.broker.config.util.MessageFlowControl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.broker.config.util.MessageFlowControl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:653)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:619)

### Could not find the main class: com.ibm.broker.config.util.MessageFlowControl.  Program will exit.

I am not sure, where I am doing mistake. Request your help on this. Thanks.

Regards,
Jeevan

Comment: Please specify more technology-specific tags. Your's are useless. Is it all about websphere?

Comment: Hi Jeeven,    I'm guessing a little here, but I would say that when you run the batch file manually, your environment vars are set to point to the necessary MQ runtime files. When the MQ Trigger is called, this is not the case. The easiest way to fix this would be to extend the PATH variable inside your Batch file... HTH